How do I get the log of rejected rows in a copy request in psycopg2?
The postgresql 17 version is used as the database.
I use parameters in copy request: ON_ERROR, LOG_VERBOSITY
COPY PUBLIC.TEST_TABLE(
       TEST
       )
       FROM STDIN
       WITH (
       FORMAT CSV,
       ON_ERROR IGNORE,
       LOG_VERBOSITY VERBOSE

When the lines are rejected, I get this log.
Example:
skipping row due to data type incompatibility at line 1 for column "TEST": "'1abcdefg'
1 rows were skipped due to data type incompatibility

How to get this log when calling Python psycopg2?
from psycopg2 import connect
conn = connect(**conn_config)
curs = conn.cursor()
sql = """COPY PUBLIC.TEST_TABLE(
       TEST
       )
       FROM STDIN
       WITH (
       FORMAT CSV,
       ON_ERROR IGNORE,
       LOG_VERBOSITY VERBOSE 
       )"""
curs.copy_expert(sql, csv)
conn.commit()


maybe this is what you're looking for: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.notices
